Преобразовать экспоненциальное число в десятичное
у опенофис-а есть неприятный момент, при конвертации из ods в csv не сохраняется формат ячеек и вместо 9804994011857243 я получаю 9,80499401185724E+015... я попробовал обработать кодом
$number = 9.80499401185724E+015;
$decimal = number_format($number, 0, '.', '');
echo $decimal;

но получаю 9804994011857240, что не соответствует оригиналу... подскажите, что я ещё могу сделать, чтобы экспоненту перевести в десятичное число без ошибок? пробовал парсить ods файл, но подружить с библиотекой ODFphp, мне не удалось...
заранее большое спасибо за помощь!

Точность числа уже потеряна и восстановлению не подлежит. Может надо выставить этим ячейкам строковый формат, а не числовой?

Если в плюс, то вряд ли потеряна

Ребята, я уже решил эту беду! Выставил строковый формат и всё прошло на отлично!
